# DataContractSerializer. Export metadata into one namespace

Tags: c#, wcf, metadata, datacontractserializer, svcutil.exe

I want to svcutil to export metadata from my libraries into one xsd file. As it divides metadata into different files by namespace, I want to redefine it for all classes to sole namespace.
I can "try" do it by two ways:
1) Redefine it for each class in DataContract attribute like this
[DataContract(Namespace="http://mynamspace.com")]
but i get the next obstacle - [I can't set atribute on class that is derived from standard class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015445/datacontractserializer-attributing-derived-class)

2)Redefine namespace for each namespace in assembly, which includes exporting classes.
[assembly: ContractNamespaceAttribute(SerializationConstants.DefaultNamespace, ClrNamespace = "UBP.AddInfo")]
But here, I challenge another problem - this directive doesn't reflect on enumeratons. They remain being exported into namespace as it defined in assembly. So it forced me to set attribute DataContract to these enums directly. BUT!!!! in this case enumeration is exported incorrectly. Instead of

```
  <xs:simpleType name="AddInfoValueType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="String" />
      <xs:enumeration value="DateTime" />
      <xs:enumeration value="Number" />
      <xs:enumeration value="BynaryData" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

I get

```
  <xs:simpleType name="AddInfoValueType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string" />
  </xs:simpleType>
```

Has anyone challenged such problems?

Comment: Is there any specific reason on why you want them to be in one namespace

Comment: It was seemed to me, that it would be more convenietnt, when there would be one xsd file. And another reason is that svcutil doesn't create attribute schemaLocation in each xsd file, that imports another namespace located in another generated file. So I must do it by myself. I wrote little app for this

Comment: Thanks, I'll note your workaround. By now, I have no services and have no need for wsdl. I wrote small app that automatically update import element with schemaLocation attribute in generated xsd files

Comment: @Rajesh if you're going to shamelessly rip off Christian Weyer's work it would be nice to credit him http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2007/05/improving-wcf-interoperability-flattening-your-wsdl.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. This is generally the route I'd go - gives you precise control. And the issue with deriving from a system type. There is an old joke Man: "doctor doctor it hurts when I do this" Doctor: "Then don't do it". I'd avoid deriving from system types on my service boundaries and just define the data you want to transport. Obviously I don't know your exact situation but that's the general approach I'd take
2. You can mix and match the two approaches - You should be able to annotate the enums  with `[DataContract]` and each enum member with `[EnumMember]` and that should give you what you need

Comment: Sometimes there is no other way, except deriving from system types. Moreover, this is not prohibited, isn't it?

Comment: Hmm - can you give an example when you have no choice? I must admit I've never needed to - its only since they introduced POCO support in .NET 3.5 SP1 that its been possible

Comment: I have class that describes custom configuration section. It must be derived from System.Configuration.ConfigSection class:
public class RApplicationDirectoriesSection : ConfigurationSection
Since all publicly visible classes in assembly are exported into xsd it also automatically goes into it. But, without DataContract attribute it goes with default namespace. If I want to change it, I need to apply DataContract attribute on it with specified namespace. When that svcutil gives me error, that I've described earlier:

Comment: Error: Type 'UBP.Configuration.Core.RAssemblyConfigurationElement' cannot inherit from a type that is not marked with DataContractAttribute or SerializableAttribute.

Comment: You have data required for your custom config section - you can pass that data using a normal class and recreate the custom config section on the client - you must remember you are not actually passing a config section - you are serializing data represented by the class that derives from the system type -WSDL is ignorant of the system config type

Comment: The fact is that I don't need to use this class in data transfer. This class is one of the classes that make core of our system. Some of them we want to export to xsd, others, like this, are exported as svcutil process every public class in assembly. And because of that I need to attribute classes that are not actually used in datatransfer

Comment: Hmmm - are you running svcutil against the assembly directly or using it to built a client from generated WSDL?

Comment: Running svcutil against assembly, trying to export metadata into xsd file

Comment: We want to build exchange of business classes between client and server in form of xml and publish format of exchange in form of xsd. We suppose that this would let us to universalize exchange not only between our client and server, but also between our server and thirdparty clients. We want to make server procedures of saving/updating objects to get only one parameter - serialized xml view of object

Comment: And that is why we trying to use wcf serialiser

Comment: I think you have two other options - separate out the types that you don't want exported into separate assemblies and only run svcutil over the assemblies that have exportable types. Create service contracts that only contain the types you want exported and run svcutil without the /dconly flag

Comment: Service contract can't describe data in class. It describes interface of interaction. I think I should accept the fact that of extraneous types in xsd, because I can't redesign assemblies

Comment: I know that service contract does this but svcutil only exports the types used on the contract if you don't use /dconly - you could even put these service contracts in a separate assembly and run svcutil against that to generate the xsd you want (I'm assuming the XSD is the end goal here)